# How to send messages between instances of a smart contract in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, messaging, smartcontracts

In a Hyperledger Fabric Network, I would like the *different instances* of a smart contract in *different peers* to be able to communicate through messages (let say for example, a communication could be a message with text string).

Then I would like that the instances of the smart contract receiving the message to be able to invoke a smart contract method based on the message content (like in a switch/case control flow statement) or send its own message to the network.

**Example:**

- We have a network made of several organizations. Each organization has a copy of the distributed ledger and an instance of a smart contract up and running.
- Let say that a smart contract can read the ledger at a specific index and triggers an event message when it read the ledger. The event message could for example contain the name of the reader and the time of the read.
- Then when another instance of the smart contract receives the message, it could either send another message to all the peers or invoke a smart contract method.

I would appreciate if anyone has a solution for this use case but any ideas, thoughts or pointers would be also highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has already been [proposed](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-11980) in the past, and I implemented a prototype of it [here](https://github.com/yacovm/fabric2/tree/p2p).

From a high level point of view, the way it works is that a smart contract has an ability to send a message to the same smart contract running the same transaction, on another peer by sending the message to its peer, and asking it to route it to a specific peer. That peer, sends the message through the native Fabric communication infrastructure (the same used for disseminating blocks) and that remote peer forwards the message to the chaincode and inside the chaincode it routes it to the right transaction.

If you want, you can roll your own fork of Fabric and cherry pick the commits, or just use this one, but note that this fork is from 2 years ago, so all the bug fixes and security fixes in these 2 years do not exist there.

Comment: Good News, thanks ! Do you know if this prototype is adaptable to Fabric 2.0 ?